# Vlookup and concatenate to pull data from survey results and show in dashboard

Tags: excel, google-sheets, concatenation, vlookup

[image]

Dashboard shows the names of associates:

```
Question #1 =       Yes:[name1, name 2]   No:[name1, name2...nameX]
Question #2 =     Proficient [name1, name2 name3...nameX]   NotProficient []
```

Sample survey data in different tab:

```
Names                   Question 1       Question 2
associate 1               Yes            Not Proficient
associate 2                No            Not Proficient
associate 3               Yes            Proficient
associate 4               Yes            Proficient
associate 5                No            Proficient
```

I need to a formula to look up the answer (yes, no) then see/match who answered it. Then put those names on the dashboard to in a single cell (yes or no section) separated with ",".

I will appreciate any help I can get here :) Thank you kindly.

Baris

Comment: Which do you want Excel or Google Sheets?  The are different in how they will accomplish this.

Comment: How did you edit the data tables? This is my first post and found it challenging :)

Comment: I would like to learn both if possible. My company recently transition to Sheets but we still have excel as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom function solution?

```
Option Explicit
Function DISPLAYRESULTS(question As Range, answers As Range, associates As Range)

    Dim finalresult As String
    Dim answerslist As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim j As Long

    ReDim answerslist(0 To 0)
    j = 0
    finalresult = question.Value & " = "

    For Each cell In answers
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, answerslist, 0)) Then
            ReDim Preserve answerslist(0 To j)
            answerslist(j) = cell.Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    For j = 0 To UBound(answerslist)
        finalresult = finalresult & answerslist(j) & ":["

        For Each cell In associates
            If cell.Offset(0, answers.Column - associates.Column).Value = answerslist(j) Then
                finalresult = finalresult & cell.Value & ", "
            End If
        Next cell

        finalresult = Left(finalresult, Len(finalresult) - 2) & "] "
    Next j

    DISPLAYRESULTS = finalresult

End Function
```

[image: img1]

Comment: is this for sheets or excel?

Comment: This is for Excel

Comment: very advanced for me. I never tried VBA codes in excel. Thanks for your time.